# Dynamic Table View Cells overlap each other inside of a particular section of the table view

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, tableview

I have a view controller which should show a large text (like an article, which contains some images). To achieve this, I am using a dynamic table view. This table view has three sections:

The first one has only one row and the cell contains a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` (for a title).

The second one can have different number of rows and each cell consists of a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`. This is where the actual text and images of the article will be.

The last one has only one row and the cell consists of a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`. This is where the information about an author will be.

Now, to achieve this, I'm using `MVVM` design pattern and fetch information from a simple `JSON` file. Here is how the **model** looks like:

```
 struct Review: Codable {
var reviewTitleAndImage: ReviewTitle
var reviewTextAndImage: [ReviewTextAndImage]
var reviewAuthorInfo: AuthorInfo
}

struct ReviewTitle: Codable {
var imageName: String
var reviewTitle: String
}

struct ReviewTextAndImage: Codable {
var reviewText: String
var reviewImageName: String
}

struct AuthorInfo: Codable {
var authorName: String
var authorImageName: String
}
```

As you can see, it is divided into three parts (for the title info, the actual text and for the author info).

In my **ViewModel** I'm using an `enum` to distinguish between sections. Here how it looks like:

```
 enum ReviewSectionTypes {
case title
case reviewText
case reviewAuthorInfo
}
```

I have also defined a protocol to which each item (which construct sections) should conform. It has two properties: type and numberOfRows:

```
 protocol ReviewViewModelSectionItem {
var type: ReviewSectionTypes {get}
var numberOfRows: Int {get}
}

extension ReviewViewModelSectionItem {
var numberOfRows: Int {
    return 1
  }
}
```

And here are the items:

```
 class TitleItem: ReviewViewModelSectionItem {
var type: ReviewSectionTypes {
    return .title
}
var numberOfRows: Int {
    return 1
}

var titleImageName: String
var titleText: String

init(titleImageName: String, titleText: String) {
    self.titleImageName = titleImageName
    self.titleText = titleText
   }
}

class ReviewText: ReviewViewModelSectionItem {
var type: ReviewSectionTypes {
    return .reviewText
}

var numberOfRows: Int {

    return reviewTextsAndImages.count
}

var reviewTextsAndImages: [ReviewTextAndImage]

init (reviewTextsAndImages: [ReviewTextAndImage]) {
    self.reviewTextsAndImages = reviewTextsAndImages
 }
}

class ReviewAuthorInfo: ReviewViewModelSectionItem {
var type: ReviewSectionTypes {
    return .reviewAuthorInfo
}

var authorName: String
var authorImageName: String

init (authorName: String, authorImageName: String) {
    self.authorName = authorName
    self.authorImageName = authorImageName
}

}
```

In the initialization of my `ViewModel` I parse the JSON and configure each item. After that, I create three types of cells to use inside of the table view.

Here is the `dataSource` of the table view (sectionItems is an `Array` which contains items after configuring them during the initialization of the `ViewModel`):

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print ("SECTIONS NUMBER:", sectionItems.count)
    return sectionItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print (sectionItems[section].numberOfRows, sectionItems[section].numberOfRows)
    return sectionItems[section].numberOfRows
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let sectionItem = sectionItems[indexPath.section]

    switch sectionItem.type {
    case .title:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TitleTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? TitleTableViewCell {
            cell.item = sectionItem
            return cell
        }

    case .reviewText:
        if let item = sectionItem as? ReviewText, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ReviewTextAndImageTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ReviewTextAndImageTableViewCell {
            cell.item = item.reviewTextsAndImages[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

    case .reviewAuthorInfo:
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:    ReviewAuthorInfoTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ReviewAuthorInfoTableViewCell {
            cell.item = sectionItem
            return cell
        }
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

And my **view controller**:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var reviewViewModel = ReviewViewModel()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = reviewViewModel
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    tableView.register(TitleTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: TitleTableViewCell.identifier)
    tableView.register(ReviewTextAndImageTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ReviewTextAndImageTableViewCell.identifier)
    tableView.register(ReviewAuthorInfoTableViewCell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: ReviewAuthorInfoTableViewCell.identifier)
}
```

The problem is, the first section is set up normally, however, inside of the second section cells overlap each other, and the third section doesn't get configured at all (the dequeue method doesn't get called for the third type of cell). So, because of these issues, the table view can't be scrolled completely towards its bottom.

I think the problem is related to the second section configuration in the table view `data source` but I can't find it.

If you know what causes the issue, or you know a better way to implement a long text with images (like in an article), I would really appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Is the source code was available? Anyway, you may wish to try reducing the json so there is just 1 cell of each type and at the same time for each of the cells add a translucent background colour (make one pink one green and one orange for example). then debug it like that to try and discern some insight into how things are being rendered. However the issue will probably be related to the height of the cells being calculated or defined before the variable length of json text has been added to the relevant part of the cell.

Comment: @Damo, I've written all code except for the code inside of the cells but there is really nothing too important there. I just configure cells by providing some data to labels and imageViews. I'll try to debug it the way you suggested. Thanks

Comment: Can you share demo code to check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To issue was because the table view was setting a wrong height for the row in the second section. To solve that problem I used heightForRowAt `UITableViewDelegate` method. Inside of it I return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

I'm not sure why, but setting `tableView` `rowHeight` property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` inside of a `viewDidLoad` didn't work. Maybe, at that time the labels inside of the cells don't have their text.

If you know the exact reason, share it with us, please.

P.s. Thanks to @Damo for showing me the right direction to think.

Comment: @Tigaran Where you have defined `UITabeleViewAutomationDimension` in cellforrowatindexpath of somewhere else??